# Warum gibt's keinen Umlaut für e und i?

Tags: pronunciation, history, umlaut

Warum gibt's keinen Umlaut für *e* und *i?*
Oder, anders gesagt: Warum gibt es *ä, ö, ü* in der deutschen Sprache, aber nicht *ï* und *ë*?

Comment: Weil die deutsche Sprache diese Laute nicht braucht? (Ausser natürlich, um den Namen eines ehemaligen VW-Vorstandsvorsitzenden zu schreiben)

Comment: Die tatsächliche Systematik der Vokale ist eine andere: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vokal#Vokale_in_der_artikulatorischen_Phonetik

Comment: @tofro Der Buchstabe im Namen des VW-Menschen (sowie in jenem eines Comedians) ist kein eigener Laut.

Comment: @Jan - Dasdas kein *Umlaut* ist, ist bekannt - Trotzdem schreibt er sich (Wie auch das Auto aus Frankreich) mit einem ë.

Comment: Zwar keine Umlaute sonder Trema, aber diese Zeichen gibt es sehr wohl: [Bernhard Hoëcker](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernhard_Hoëcker) und [Zaïre](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zaïre_(Währung)) oder [Aïda](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aida_(Unternehmen))

Comment: @CarstenS vote retracted

Comment: Orthographisch ist _é_ das Umlaut-_e_ und _y_ das Umlaut-_i_, da sie zumindest bestimmte _ee_ bzw. _ie_ ersetzen können, aber gefragt ist sehr wahrscheinlich nach einer phonologischen Erklärung.

Answer (score 8):

Das liegt an der Entwicklung der deutschen (und anderen germanischen) Sprache aus dem indoeuropäischen Vorläufer.

Das Indoeuropäische kennt nur fünf verschiedene Vokallaute, die sich in den meisten indoeuropäischen Sprachen als /a/, /e/, /i/, /o/ und /u/ wiedergeben lassen. (Unterschiede in Vokallänge und -qualität seien in dieser Diskussion außen vor gelassen.) Im Laufe der Zeit entwickelten sich diese Vokallaute auseinander; so wurde zum Beispiel im Griechischen jedes /u/ systematisch zu einem [y].

In den germanischen Sprachen hat sich eine besondere Lautverschiebung ergeben, die vor Allem durch einen /e/- oder /i/-Laut in einer Folgesilbe verursacht wurde, und die hauptsächlich betonte Silben betraf: der Umlaut. Dieser macht aus einem a ein ä, aus einem o ein ö und aus einem u ein ü. (Diese Verschiebungen existieren in allen germanischen Sprachen, nicht aber in nahe verwandten indoeuropäischen.)

Wenn man sich diese Laute und ihre Produktion im Mund durch das Zusammenspiel von Zunge und Lippen anschaut, stellt man fest, dass es sich bei diesen Umlauten um eine Bewegung hin zu /e/ oder /i/ handelt: /o/ und /u/ sind hintere Vokale (artikuliert werden sie im hinteren Bereich des Mundes), /e/ und /i/ vordere. Werden /o/ oder /u/ nach vorne verschoben, ohne dabei die Rundung der Lippen zu ändern, ergeben sich /ö/ und /ü/. Das /a/ ist ein mittlerer Vokal und ungerundet, was bedeutet, dass dieser Laut schlicht dem /e/ ähnlicher geworden ist (ä und e lassen sich nicht unterscheiden, wenn das e kurz und betont ist).

Dieser Hintergrund zeigt uns, dass /e/ und /i/ gar nicht nach diesem Mechanismus verschoben werden können, denn sie sind ja schon »das Ziel«.

Answer (score 2):

A. o, and u are what an American English speaker would call "hard" vowels. E and I are "soft" vowels. Although this concept is used to described [Swedish vowels](https://blogs.transparent.com/swedish/swedish-pronunciation-hard-and-soft-vowels/) the equivalent German (and Swedish) terms terms appear to be "back" and "front" vowels (in relation to the mouth).

Umlauts over a, o, and u bring these vowels to the "front." As Jan noted, these vowels are pronounced with rounded lips. E and i are already frontal vowels and need no forwarding.

A, o und u sind was ein Amerikaneder "harte" Vokale nennt. E und i sind "weiche" Vokale. Obwohl dieses Konzept verwendet wird, um [schwedische Vokale](https://blogs.transparent.com/swedish/swedish-pronunciation-hard-and-soft-vowels/) zu beschreiben, scheinen die äquivalenten deutschen (und schwedischen) Terme  hintere (back) - und vordere (front) -Vokale (in Bezug auf den Mund) zu sein.

Umlaute, die über a, o und u gelegt werden, bringen sie "vorne". Wie Jan bemerkt, sind diese Vokale mit abgerundeten Lippen ausgesprochen. Aber e und i brauchen keine Umlaute, um sie vordere zu bringen, weil sie schon vordere sind.

Comment: Die englischen Kategorien "weich" und "hart" passen für das Deutsche nicht.

Comment: Ah, thanks, now I know what you are talking about. Incidentally, the first sentence of that website (‘Swedish has nine vowels’) is about as wrong as can be. The three *A*s in *Arlanda* represent three different sounds. *U* can be rendered in at least three qualitatively different ways. *O* should have four variants. And so it goes on.

Comment: @Janka: I "translated" my Americanisms, "soft "and "hard "vowels into "front" and "back" vowels in line with German usage, and cited a source on Swedish vowels that uses both sets of terms. Thanks for your help